# Show Friendly error for common EF Delete Statement conflicts with reference restraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi 2 service backed by Entity Framework.  When a user tries to delete an entity that has some other entity relating to it, I just want to show them a message stating they can't delete that particular item because some other item has a relationship to it, and skip the delete.

I'm assuming this has to be a fairly common scenario.  I'm currently using a try-catch statement to throw a friendly message in an HTTP response message.  This feels like a hack to me...  I'd love to hear other suggestions for ways to handle this.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = await TheContext.Fluids.FindAsync(id);
            if (entity == null) return NotFound();
            TheContext.Fluids.Remove(entity);
            await TheContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (CannotDeleteDueToExistingRelationship(ex))
                ThrowForbiddenCannotDeleteDueToExistingRelationship();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
//Methods in base controller
protected void ThrowForbiddenCannotDeleteDueToExistingRelationship()
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("This entity has a relationship to another item and cannot be deleted.")),
            ReasonPhrase = "Relationship requires entity."
        });
    }

   protected bool CannotDeleteDueToExistingRelationship(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple once I found it.  WebAPI 2 allows you to use an attribute filter.

```
 public class DeleteConflictsWithReferenceConstraintExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (!(context.Exception as DbUpdateException).InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint")) return;
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("This entity has a relationship to another item and cannot be deleted.")),
                ReasonPhrase = "Relationship requires entity."
            };
            context.Response = response;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then registered in the WebApiConfig.

```
private static void WebApiConfig(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var webApiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
    webApiConfig.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    // Web API filters
    webApiConfig.Filters.Add(new DbEntityValidationExceptionAttribute());
    webApiConfig.Filters.Add(new DeleteConflictsWithReferenceConstraintExceptionAttribute());
}
```

This avoids having the same exception logic everywhere.